# Batch file to edit a text file and replace text

Tags: batch-file, replace

I need to create a batch file that will open a text file look for a specific text and replace it with another word. Then save the file and rename it to .reg when its done.

Comment: what kind of batch file? WIndows .BAT, Unix .SH?

Comment: @rcdmk: People who don't specify what kind of batch file almost always mean Windows .Bat.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
if exist %~N1.reg del %~N1.reg
for /F "delims=" %%l in (%1) do (
    set "line=%%l"
    set "line=%line:specific text=another word%"
    echo/%line%>> %~N1.reg
)
```

This is a very simple Batch file that should work on most cases. It have, however, some problems if file contents may have special Batch characters, like | > < & etc. However, this limitation may be fixed if it is required.

Comment: I need this to be something that uses variables. Like it opens \\fileshare\%username%\filename.reg find all instances of a string like "printername" and replace with "newprintername" save the file back as .reg

Comment: If you see the link I've posted in my answer you will realise that its exactly what you need

Answer (score 1):

If this is for Windows you can use this: http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace

> This batch allows string substitution in a text file. It parses each line of a text file for a particular string and replaces it with another string. 
>   I.e. To replace all occurrences of "Yellow Submarine" in "color.txt" with "uboot" and put the output on the screen run:
>   `BatchSubstitute.bat "Yellow Submarine" uboot color.txt`
>   Or
>   `type color.txt|BatchSubstitute.bat "Yellow Submarine" uboot`
>
> Optionally pipe the output into a new file, i.e.
>   `BatchSubstitute.bat "Yellow Submarine" uboot color.txt>newfile.txt`
>   Or
>   `type color.txt|BatchSubstitute.bat "Yellow Submarine" uboot>newfile.txt`

```
@echo off
REM -- Prepare the Command Processor --
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
SETLOCAL DISABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

::BatchSubstitude - parses a File line by line and replaces a substring"
::syntax: BatchSubstitude.bat OldStr NewStr File
::          OldStr [in] - string to be replaced
::          NewStr [in] - string to replace with
::          File   [in] - file to be parsed
:$changed 20100115
:$source http://www.dostips.com
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=]" %%A in ('"type %3|find /n /v """') do (
    set "line=%%B"
    if defined line (
        call set "line=echo.%%line:%~1=%~2%%"
        for /f "delims=" %%X in ('"echo."%%line%%""') do %%~X
    ) ELSE echo.
)
```